# Time until next collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm coding a simulation of a 2D gas (circles of radius R) and I need to find the time of the next collision between two specific particles.

Since the particles move in a straight line between collisions:

$\vec{r'} = \vec{r} + \vec{v}.t$

and the condition for collision is:

$||\vec{r_j} - \vec{r_i}|| = 2R$

And I end up with an ugly 2nd order polynomial:

$$[(v_{x,j} - v_{x,i})^2+(v_{y,j} - v_{y,i})^2]t^2 + 2[(x_j-x_i)(v_{x,j}-v_{x,i}) + (y_j-y_i)(v_{y,j}-v_{y,i})]t + [(x_j-x_i)^2+(y_j-y_i)^2-(2R)^2] = 0$$

or $at^2 + bt + c = 0$

Since $\frac{c}{a} \geq 0$, the roots will have the same sign.

So, either I've made a mistake somewhere, or there is something I don't understand because, what am I supposed to do if I get two positive times ? Which one am I supposed to choose ?

Comment: Is your goal to calculate the mean collision time from the statistics of the system or do you need it for additional calculations? If it's the latter you can probably use $\tau=\frac{1}{n\sigma v}$, where $n=N/V$ and $\sigma=4R^2\pi$ is the collision cross section.

Comment: I need to calculate the exact time of the next collision for each particle in order to make the collision happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brief answer**

Choose the least time.

**Justification**

Forget for a second you are dealing with particles.

Imagine a circle of radius $R$ with its centre gliding at constant speed along a line which contains the centre of another circle of radius $R$. The distance between the two centres will be $2R$ exactly twice: once when the two circles first touch, and again when the two circles touch for the last time. (Before and after they are disjoint,in between, they intersect).

The case generalises if you imagine the first centre "missing" the second one by a distance of less than $2R$. The two times get closer together as the first misses the second one by more, until they are the same when the two circles just brush each other.

What your quadratic equation is finding are these two times: the only data you input in the equation is the initial positions and the constant velocities. Your equation does not *know* that you are dealing with atoms that will rebound! It only knows about the centres of mass moving along straight lines. If you want the collision time to add the rebound, you will have to pick the least of the two solutions.

Comment: It seems so obvious now that you've pointed it out :)